# Populate value in second drop down according to first dropdown value

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Database table is as follows:

```
id  |  model  |  type
1       M1        T1
2       M1        T2
3       M2        T3
4       M3        T4
5       M3        T5
```

I have populate my first drowpdown name Model with distinct models from database

```
<select id="sen_model" name="sen_model" required="true" onchange="copy();">
    <option value="0" disabled selected> -- select sensor model -- </option>'
    <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("project1") or die("Cannot Connect to database");
        $query= mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT model from sensor_info");
        while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $id=$row['id'];
            $model=$row['model'];
            echo '<option value="'.$model.'">'.$model.'</option>';                      
        }   
        Print  '</select>
        </th>
        <th>
            <select id="sen_type" name="sen_type" required="true">
                <option value="0" disabled selected> -- select sensor type -- </option>';

        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("project1") or die("Cannot Connect to database");
        $query= mysql_query("SELECT * from sensor_info");
        while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $id=$row['id'];
            $type=$row['type'];
            echo '<option value="'.$type.'">'.$type.'</option>';                        
        }
    ?>              
</select>
```

Now I need to change second drop-down values depending on first drop-down.
That will be possible if value of first drop-down stored in php variable so that we can use php variable in mysql query.

Its much better if value of first drop-down saved in php variable.

This should not have any POST or GET action to get values so keep in mind, i have to implement just after selecting a value in first drop-down.

mysql query of second drop-down will also change accordingly.

Comment: First of all no need to connect many times to your mysql and select the db, one time is enough.
After the thing you want to do is better with jquery. you should post your datas from the first form with an ajax call, and grab in the callback the data of the second one.

Comment: ok thanks for the information. Now what about the remaining

Comment: the behaviour you want is for example the same as a postcode form that display the list of cities below after select.
After the thing you want to do is better with jquery. you should post your first form data with an ajax call, and grab in the callback the data of the second one.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
you will have to post on another php page probably, and in this page do a php code that retrieves date to fill the second form ( ideally encode it in json)

Then you just have to make a js loop on this json to fill your options for the second input, make it visible and it is good.